# 'Bizarre' ordering of sets in python

Tags: python

When I convert a Python 3.8.0 list to a set, the resulting set ordering* is highly structured in a non-trivial way. How is this structure being extracted from the pseudo-random list?

---

As part of an experiment I am running, I am generating a random set. I was surprised to see that plotting the set suddenly showed unexpected linear structure in the set. So there are two things puzzling me - why does converting to a set result have an ordering* which ends up highlighting this structure; and, to a lesser extent why does the pseudo-random set have this "hidden" structure at all?

The code:

```py
X = [randrange(250) for i in range(30)]
print(X)
print(set(X))
```

which outputs, for example

```py
[238, 202, 245, 94, 111, 106, 148, 164, 154, 113, 128, 10, 196, 141, 69, 38, 106, 8, 40, 53, 160, 87, 85, 13, 38, 147, 204, 50, 162, 91]

{128, 8, 10, 141, 13, 147, 148, 154, 160, 162, 164, 38, 40, 50, 53, 196, 69, 202, 204, 85, 87, 91, 94, 106, 238, 111, 113, 245}
```

A plot** of the above list looks fairly random, as expected:

[image: WolframAlpha plot of randomly generated list]

whereas plotting the set (as it is ordered in the output) exhibits the structure present in the set:

[image: WolframAlpha plot of set from random list]

This behaviour 100% consistent on my machine (more examples below) with the values 250 and 30 used in the above code (the example I used is not cherry picked - it is just the last one I ran). Tuning these values sometimes results in slightly different structure (e.g. a subset of three arithmetic progressions*** instead of two).

Is this reproducible on other people's machines? Of course, that such structure exists seems indicative of a not-so-great pseudo-random number generation, but this does not explain how converting to a set would in some sense 'extract' this structure.
As far as I am aware, the there is no formal guarantee that the ordering of a set (when converted from a list) is deterministic (and even if it is, there is no sophisticated ordering being done in the background). So how is this happening?!

---

(*): I know, sets are unordered collections, but I mean "ordered" in the sense that, when calling the `print` statement, the set is output in *some* order which consistently highlights the underlying set structure.

(**): These [plots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7B128%2C%208%2C%2010%2C%20141%2C%2013%2C%20147%2C%20148%2C%20154%2C%20160%2C%20162%2C%20164%2C%2038%2C%2040%2C%2050%2C%2053%2C%20196%2C%2069%2C%20202%2C%20204%2C%2085%2C%2087%2C%2091%2C%2094%2C%20106%2C%20238%2C%20111%2C%20113%2C%20245%7D) are from Wolfram Alpha. Two more examples are below:

[image]

(***): Two plots when changing the range of the random numbers from 250 to 500:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically, this is because of two things:

- A set in Python is implemented using a [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable),
- The hash of an integer is the integer itself.

Therefore, the index that an integer appears in the underlying array will be determined by the integer's value, modulo the length of the underlying array. So, integers will tend to stay in ascending order when you put a contiguous range of them into a set:

```py
>>> list(set(range(10000))) == list(range(10000))
True # this can't be an accident!
```

If you don't have all of the numbers from a contiguous range, then the "modulo the length of the underlying array" part comes into play:

```py
>>> r = range(0, 50, 4)
>>> set(r)
{0, 32, 4, 36, 8, 40, 12, 44, 16, 48, 20, 24, 28}
>>> sorted(r, key=lambda x: x % 32)
[0, 32, 4, 36, 8, 40, 12, 44, 16, 48, 20, 24, 28]
```

The sequence is predictable if you know the length of the underlying array, and the (deterministic) algorithm for adding elements. In this case the array's length is 32, because it's [initially 8](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d905df766c367c350f20c46ccd99d4da19ed57d8/Include/setobject.h#L24) and is [quadrupled](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4d17fd2cf69e7c8f4cd03fbf2d575370945b952/Objects/setobject.c#L248) while elements are added.

Except for a blip near the end (because the numbers 52 and 56 aren't in the set), the range is divided into two sequences `0, 4, 8, ...` and `32, 36, 40, ...` which alternate because the hashes, which are the numbers' values themselves, are taken modulo 32 to choose indices in the array. There are collisions; for example, 4 and 36 are equal modulo 32, but 4 was added to the set first so 36 ends up at a different index.

Here's a chart for this sequence. The structure in your charts is just a noisier version, because you generated your numbers randomly rather than from a range with a step.

[image]

The number of interleaved sequences will depend on the size of the set in proportion to the length of the range the numbers are sampled from, since that determines how many times the range's length "wraps around" modulo the length of the hashtable's underlying array. Here's an example with three interleaved sequences `0, 6, 12, ...`, `66, 72, 78, ...` and `36, 42, 48, ...`:

```py
>>> set(range(0, 90, 6))
{0, 66, 36, 6, 72, 42, 12, 78, 48, 18, 84, 54, 24, 60, 30}
```

Comment: Ah! That explains it (and nice explanation too)!

Comment: And of course, this pattern in the plots has nothing to do with underlying structure in the set (we would expect this pattern to arise in the plots with random lists as in my example)... I was just seduced by the unexpected patterns in the plots!

Comment: How do you find that 30 is the length of the underlying array?

Comment: @MarkSnyder It turns out it's 32, which means there are collisions, but the order is the same as if it was modulo 30.

Comment: @kaya3 I guess you found it by inspection, then? I'm curious as to why it's 32 - the length of the list fits in 16. Perhaps 32 is the minimum size.

Comment: @MarkSnyder The array will be resized [if it gets more than 2/3 full](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d5bf568eaa5059402ccce9ba5a366986ba27c8a/Objects/dictobject.c#L389), since a hashtable's performance degrades very significantly if you let the array get full or nearly-full.

Comment: I find this misleading if not wrong. You make it sound like values are stored at "their indices" in a list for each index. So that `set([0, 1, 32])` would result in the order `{0, 32, 1}` because 0 and 32 are at index 0, and 1 is at index 1. But the actual order is `{0, 1, 32}`. Another example is `set([7, 39])` which according to your explanation should result in `{7, 39}`, as both have the same index and 7 was added first. But it results in `{39, 7}`.

Comment: @HeapOverflow In those cases the set is small so the underlying array size is 8, and 7 is at the last index, so when 39 collides, it obviously has to go at an earlier index because there isn't a later one. Likewise for `{0, 1, 32}`, the number 0 gets put at index 0, then 1 goes at index 1, then of course 32 can't go in between them. Those are just different things that can happen when collisions occur, but they didn't happen in my example so it wasn't necessary to explain them (and they don't significantly impact the phenomenon observed by the OP).

Comment: That's the real explanation, yes. That's not what your answer's explanation sounds like, though. [Separate chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining)) is a thing, and your answer sounds like that's used here.

Comment: I don't think my answer sounds like there are lists at each index, but I welcome a suggestion for a better wording.

Comment: *"taken modulo 32 to choose their indices in the array"* suggests they each have *one* index to go to (namely their value modulo 32), and the additional *"appears first because it was added to the set first"* suggests they're stored at "their index" in order. Anyway, not really in the mood to rewrite :-). Btw, your links all go to dictobject.c instead of setobject.c, and they're not equivalent.

Comment: I'm aware that `dictobject.c` and `setobject.c` are not implemented exactly the same way; but `setobject.c` doesn't have the same explanatory comments, and it doesn't define the initial size or the growth rate as constants/macros, so I thought links to `dictobject.c` would be more useful for understanding. They are both hashtables, and they are implemented similarly enough that the OP's phenomenon should occur in both, except for the fact that you don't observe the underlying array's order when you iterate over a dict.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I've edited to address those points; thanks for your comments.

Comment: Nice, small change dealing with both issues. Though the vague "a different index" makes the "exactly predictable" less convincing (sorry :-). Maybe the dict constants/macros are easier to understand, but "doubled twice" isn't right, as it really is [quadrupled once](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4d17fd2cf69e7c8f4cd03fbf2d575370945b952/Objects/setobject.c#L248). Experimental confirmation [here](https://repl.it/repls/LankyDarkScope).

Comment: @HeapOverflow Ah, when I said "exactly predictable" I didn't mean that the rest of my answer would describe a complete algorithm for making such predictions! Thanks for finding that, I've fixed the part about the growth rate, and found the right link for the initial set size.